# using $htmlOptions to add CSS in errorSummary()

Tags: yii

i don't see what i'm missing here. i'm trying to add a class to the errorSummary() but i keep getting errors. Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

```
<?php echo $form->errorSummary($model, array('htmlOptions' => array('class' => 'alert alert-block alert-error'))); ?>
```

is says $htmlOptions is an array http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#errorSummary-detail

here is my error

```
Array to string conversion
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
<?php echo $form->errorSummary($model, '', '', array('class' => 'alert alert-error')); ?>
```

leave `$header` and `$footer` blank, and just pass the class as `$htmlOptions`